# Powershell Prompt for input

Tags: powershell

I have a few lines of powershell code that looks in a remote directory

```
Get-ChildItem "\\box_lab001\f$\output files" -force | 
    Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer -AND $_.lastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) } | 
    Select-Object LastWriteTime,@{n="Path";e={convert-path $_.PSPath}} | 
    Tee-Object "\\\box_lab001\c$\Users\john\Documents\output files_root.txt" | 
    Remove-Item -force
```

What I'm looking to do is make this scalable across multiple boxes where if a user sees an issue on box_lab01, trough 10. Then he can run the script with a switch that will ask for input. It would then run the command separately, replacing box_lab### each time, possible?

`C:\powershell.ps1 -input
what boxes are having the issue? use three digit numbers only, comma separated`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can use [`Read-Host`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx) to prompt for input. You can use `param(...)` to add parameters to a script:

```
param($input = $null)
if ($input) {
    $foo = Read-Host -Prompt $input
}
```

You can then get the individual numbers by using `-split`:

```
$numbers = $foo -split ','
```

Loop over them:

```
$numbers | ForEach-Object {
  ...
}
```

You can use `$_` within the block to refer to the current number.

Comment: and then some sort of for loop so that it loops through the script once with each param?

Comment: I think you're better off reading the documentation first. It's really good for PowerShell.

Comment: any other clues you can give me? looking to get this done today.

Comment: I figured it out to the point where I have the user enter the three digit values seperated by a comma and get that to print out as a list. Now I dont' know how to tell it to sub in each one of those values into my code?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a parameter that takes an array of values as input.  You can then use these to check each machine:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [int[]]
    # The numbers of the machines whose output files should be removed.
    $MachineNumbers
)

$MachineNumbers | ForEach-Object {
    $machineRoot = '\\box_lab{0:d3}' -f $_ 
    Get-ChildItem ('{0}\f$\output files' -f $machineRoot) -force | 
        Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer -AND $_.lastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) } | 
        Select-Object LastWriteTime,@{n="Path";e={convert-path $_.PSPath}} | 
        Tee-Object ('{0}\c$\Users\john\Documents\output files_root.txt' -f $machineRoot)  | 
        Remove-Item -force
```

The code `('\\box_lab{{0:d3}}' -f $_)` converts each number passed from the user into a zero-padded, three character string (which appears to be your compuer naming schem).  You would then call your script like this:

```
 Remove-OutputFiles -MachineNumbers (1..10)
 Remove-OutputFiles -MachineNumbers 1,2,3,4,5
```

You could give the `MachineNumbers` parameter a reasonable default, so that if no parameters are passed, it hits a  default set of machines.

I would also uae the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute to your script so you can pass `-WhatIf` to your script and see what files will be deleted without actually deleting them:

```
Remove-OutputFiles -MachineNumbers (1..3) -WhatIf
```